# Как написать реализацию firend функции в cpp файле

Tags: c++

Объявил в классе TimeSpan в файле timespan.hpp дружественные функции:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream out, const TimeSpan t);
friend TimeSpan operator+(const TimeSpan &t1, const TimeSpan &t2);
friend TimeSpan operator-(const TimeSpan &t, const TimeSpan &t2);
```

Но как начинаю писать реализацию в cpp файле пишет, что TimeSpan не содержит члена operator+

```
TimeSpan TimeSpan::operator+(const TimeSpan &t1, const TimeSpan &t2) {
    ....
}
```

В чем проблема, как можно это исправить?

Comment: просто `TimeSpan operator+(const TimeSpan &t1, const TimeSpan &t2) { /*...*/ }`

Comment: То есть реализацию дружественных функций пишут в hpp файле? В cpp никак нельзя?

Comment: В cpp. Просто TimeSpan:: не нужно писать

Comment: уберите TimeSpan:: и все должно заработать.

Comment: это же дружественная свободная функция, а не метод класса. соответственно TimeSpan:: не нужно

Answer (score 0):

Дружественная функция не принадлежит классу в том смысле, в котором мы привыкли. Поэтому область видимости для неё прописывать не нужно (ту штуку до двух двоеточий)

```
TimeSpan operator+(const TimeSpan &t1, const TimeSpan &t2) {
    ....
}
```

Лишит вас всех проблем

Comment: что значит "в том смысле, в котором мы привыкли"? В другом, для нас не в привычном, смысле принадлежит?... И зачем повторять ответ из комментариев?...

Comment: @ARHovsepyan потому что в каком-то смысле она всё же принадлежит к классу. Она имеет доступ к его приватным членам + мы банально видим её в файле класса.

Если не ответить, то вопрос выводится в топы, ибо неотвеченный.

Comment: @DiHASTRO она не принадлежит классу от слова совсем. Просто область видимости класса расширяется на дружественную функцию. Дружественные функции не имеют указателя this, поэтому не принадлежат классу и не являются его методами